# Unable to get SQL Server to run backups successfully

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server backups running on several machines & keep getting stopped every few days with the same error:

> The database is in an invalid state for backups: ??????????\SQLEXPRESS\LexTimeTrackingHubSQL. State = Normal, AutoClosed
>   Explanation: The server reported that the database is not in a state that permits backups, such as AutoClose, Recovery, or Offline.
>   Resolution: Change the state and try again.

From forums online I have noticed a workaround: to change the SQL Server database autoclose option in properties to true then back to false & save each time. The next day this works but then fails after 2 or 3 more backups.

My question is does anyone know of a more permanent fix?

The machines it is failing on so far are running these OSes:

- Windows Server 2012R2
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows 10 Creators update installed
- Windows 7 SP1.

Many thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Leave AutoClose off permanently? The reason given is AutoClosed so something's changing it to On.

Comment: AutoClose is off permanently already this is alert despite this unfortunately.